# coredns pods have CrashLoopBackOff or Error state

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, coredns

I'm trying to set up the Kubernetes master, by issuing:

> kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

1. followed by: [Installing a pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) (Calico)
2. followed by: [Master Isolation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#master-isolation)

---

issue: `coredns` pods have `CrashLoopBackOff` or `Error` state:

```
# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-lflwx                          2/2     Running            0          2d
coredns-576cbf47c7-nm7gc                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   69         2d
coredns-576cbf47c7-nwcnx                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   69         2d
etcd-suey.nknwn.local                      1/1     Running            0          2d
kube-apiserver-suey.nknwn.local            1/1     Running            0          2d
kube-controller-manager-suey.nknwn.local   1/1     Running            0          2d
kube-proxy-xkgdr                           1/1     Running            0          2d
kube-scheduler-suey.nknwn.local            1/1     Running            0          2d
#
```

I tried with [Troubleshooting kubeadm - Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state), however my node isn't running `SELinux` and my Docker is up to date.

```
# docker --version
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
#
```

`kubectl`'s `describe`:

```
# kubectl -n kube-system describe pod coredns-576cbf47c7-nwcnx 
Name:               coredns-576cbf47c7-nwcnx
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               suey.nknwn.local/192.168.86.81
Start Time:         Sun, 28 Oct 2018 22:39:46 -0400
Labels:             k8s-app=kube-dns
                    pod-template-hash=576cbf47c7
Annotations:        cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.0.30/32
Status:             Running
IP:                 192.168.0.30
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/coredns-576cbf47c7
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://ec65b8f40c38987961e9ed099dfa2e8bb35699a7f370a2cda0e0d522a0b05e79
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:3e2be1cec87aca0b74b7668bbe8c02964a95a402e45ceb51b2252629d608d03a
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 31 Oct 2018 23:28:58 -0400
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Wed, 31 Oct 2018 23:21:35 -0400
      Finished:     Wed, 31 Oct 2018 23:23:54 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  103
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-xvq8b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-xvq8b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-xvq8b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                       Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                       -------
  Normal   Killing    54m (x10 over 4h19m)    kubelet, suey.nknwn.local  Killing container with id docker://coredns:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  Unhealthy  9m56s (x92 over 4h20m)  kubelet, suey.nknwn.local  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Warning  BackOff    5m4s (x173 over 4h10m)  kubelet, suey.nknwn.local  Back-off restarting failed container
# kubectl -n kube-system describe pod coredns-576cbf47c7-nm7gc 
Name:               coredns-576cbf47c7-nm7gc
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               suey.nknwn.local/192.168.86.81
Start Time:         Sun, 28 Oct 2018 22:39:46 -0400
Labels:             k8s-app=kube-dns
                    pod-template-hash=576cbf47c7
Annotations:        cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.0.31/32
Status:             Running
IP:                 192.168.0.31
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/coredns-576cbf47c7
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://0f2db8d89a4c439763e7293698d6a027a109bf556b806d232093300952a84359
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:3e2be1cec87aca0b74b7668bbe8c02964a95a402e45ceb51b2252629d608d03a
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 31 Oct 2018 23:29:11 -0400
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Wed, 31 Oct 2018 23:21:58 -0400
      Finished:     Wed, 31 Oct 2018 23:24:08 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  102
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-xvq8b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-xvq8b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-xvq8b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                       Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                       -------
  Normal   Killing    44m (x12 over 4h18m)    kubelet, suey.nknwn.local  Killing container with id docker://coredns:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  BackOff    4m58s (x170 over 4h9m)  kubelet, suey.nknwn.local  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  8s (x102 over 4h19m)    kubelet, suey.nknwn.local  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
#
```

`kubectl`'s `log`:

```
# kubectl -n kube-system logs -f coredns-576cbf47c7-nm7gc 
E1101 03:31:58.974836       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:348: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:31:58.974836       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:355: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:31:58.974857       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:350: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:32:29.975493       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:348: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:32:29.976732       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:355: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:32:29.977788       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:350: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:33:00.976164       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:348: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:33:00.977415       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:355: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:33:00.978332       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:350: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
2018/11/01 03:33:08 [INFO] SIGTERM: Shutting down servers then terminating
E1101 03:33:31.976864       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:348: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:33:31.978080       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:355: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E1101 03:33:31.979156       1 reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:350: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
# 

# kubectl -n kube-system log -f coredns-576cbf47c7-gqdgd
.:53
2018/11/05 04:04:13 [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.2
2018/11/05 04:04:13 [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11, eb51e8b
CoreDNS-1.2.2
linux/amd64, go1.11, eb51e8b
2018/11/05 04:04:13 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
2018/11/05 04:04:19 [FATAL] plugin/loop: Seen "HINFO IN 3597544515206064936.6415437575707023337." more than twice, loop detected
# kubectl -n kube-system log -f coredns-576cbf47c7-hhmws
.:53
2018/11/05 04:04:18 [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.2
2018/11/05 04:04:18 [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11, eb51e8b
CoreDNS-1.2.2
linux/amd64, go1.11, eb51e8b
2018/11/05 04:04:18 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
2018/11/05 04:04:24 [FATAL] plugin/loop: Seen "HINFO IN 6900627972087569316.7905576541070882081." more than twice, loop detected
#
```

`describe` (`apiserver`):

```
# kubectl -n kube-system describe pod kube-apiserver-suey.nknwn.local
Name:               kube-apiserver-suey.nknwn.local
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           2000000000
PriorityClassName:  system-cluster-critical
Node:               suey.nknwn.local/192.168.87.20
Start Time:         Fri, 02 Nov 2018 00:28:44 -0400
Labels:             component=kube-apiserver
                    tier=control-plane
Annotations:        kubernetes.io/config.hash: 2433a531afe72165364aace3b746ea4c
                    kubernetes.io/config.mirror: 2433a531afe72165364aace3b746ea4c
                    kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2018-11-02T00:28:43.795663261-04:00
                    kubernetes.io/config.source: file
                    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: 
Status:             Running
IP:                 192.168.87.20
Containers:
  kube-apiserver:
    Container ID:  docker://659456385a1a859f078d36f4d1b91db9143d228b3bc5b3947a09460a39ce41fc
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.12.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver@sha256:094929baf3a7681945d83a7654b3248e586b20506e28526121f50eb359cee44f
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      kube-apiserver
      --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
      --advertise-address=192.168.87.20
      --allow-privileged=true
      --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
      --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
      --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
      --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
      --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
      --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
      --insecure-port=0
      --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
      --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
      --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
      --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
      --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
      --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
      --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
      --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
      --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
      --secure-port=6443
      --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
      --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
      --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
      --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 04 Nov 2018 22:57:27 -0500
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sun, 04 Nov 2018 20:12:06 -0500
      Finished:     Sun, 04 Nov 2018 22:55:24 -0500
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  2
    Requests:
      cpu:        250m
    Liveness:     http-get https://192.168.87.20:6443/healthz delay=15s timeout=15s period=10s #success=1 #failure=8
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/ca-certificates from etc-ca-certificates (ro)
      /etc/kubernetes/pki from k8s-certs (ro)
      /etc/ssl/certs from ca-certs (ro)
      /usr/local/share/ca-certificates from usr-local-share-ca-certificates (ro)
      /usr/share/ca-certificates from usr-share-ca-certificates (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  etc-ca-certificates:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/ca-certificates
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  k8s-certs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/kubernetes/pki
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  ca-certs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/ssl/certs
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  usr-share-ca-certificates:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/ca-certificates
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  usr-local-share-ca-certificates:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
QoS Class:         Burstable
Node-Selectors:    <none>
Tolerations:       :NoExecute
Events:            <none>
#
```

syslog (host):

> Nov  4 22:59:36 suey kubelet[1234]: E1104 22:59:36.139538    1234
>   pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod
>   d8146b7e-de57-11e8-a1e2-ec8eb57434c8
>   ("coredns-576cbf47c7-hhmws_kube-system(d8146b7e-de57-11e8-a1e2-ec8eb57434c8)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "coredns" with
>   CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=coredns
>   pod=coredns-576cbf47c7-hhmws_kube-system(d8146b7e-de57-11e8-a1e2-ec8eb57434c8)"

Please advise.

Comment: attach the full output pls

Comment: Also try `kubectl logs -f coredns-576cbf47c7-nm7gc`

Comment: @AndreHelberg I updated my question with output from `kubectl logs` command. I'm not sure what this `10.96.0.1:443` is ...

Comment: @KonstantinVustin I updated my question with full output as well.

Comment: @alexus It looks like you are trying to set up a cluster from scratch?
I haven't done this before, so my input might not be of much help, but from the log you pasted, it seems your pod is trying to connect to `10.96.0.1:443`.

I'd suggest verifying that what ever should be there is up. I'm guessing it is `kube-apiserver-suey.nknwn.local`.
I would look at: 
* are these nodes on the same network
* Is the ip correct
* is something listening on 443
* check the service (logs) listening on 443, might be a cert/auth issue or it's timing out
* check that ports aren't being blocked

Comment: At a second glance it seems your dns node is running at 192.168.86.81 so unless you've done some serious config, I don't think it would be able to connect to 10.96.0.1

Comment: @AndreHelberg I used following command to set up the Kubernetes master: `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`, sorry no "serious config". I'm bit puzzled with what and/or where `10.96.0.1` is? as per describe output, both `coredns` containers are in 192.168.0.X network.

Comment: @alexus The coredns docs says that it should support env vars. From [kubernetes config](https://coredns.io/plugins/kubernetes/#syntax) it should be `endpoint` so I'm guessing if you restart your pod with the env var `ENDPOINT=...` where `...` is kube-apiserver-suey.nknwn.local's ip it should work

Comment: @AndreHelberg per `describe` of `apiserver`, it does looks like `10.96.X.X` is part of it (specifically: `--service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12`), maybe adjusting `--service-cidr` instead? I'm still confused what am I doing wrong (or how to fix it).

Comment: @alexus Please join [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183168/questions-53075796-coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This error

```
[FATAL] plugin/loop: Seen "HINFO IN 6900627972087569316.7905576541070882081." more than twice, loop detected
```

is caused when CoreDNS detects a loop in the resolve configuration, and it is the intended behavior. You are hitting this issue:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1162

https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2087

**Hacky solution: Disable the CoreDNS loop detection**

Edit the CoreDNS configmap:

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns
```

Remove or comment out the line with `loop`, save and exit.

Then remove the CoreDNS pods, so new ones can be created with new config:

```
kubectl -n kube-system delete pod -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```

All should be fine after that.

**Preferred Solution: Remove the loop in the DNS configuration**

First, check if you are using `systemd-resolved`. If you are running Ubuntu 18.04, it is probably the case.

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep systemd-resolved
```

If it is, check which `resolv.conf` file your cluster is using as reference:

```
ps auxww | grep kubelet
```

You might see a line like:

```
/usr/bin/kubelet ... --resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

The important part is `--resolv-conf` - we figure out if systemd resolv.conf is used, or not.

**If it is the `resolv.conf` of `systemd`, do the following:**

Check the content of `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` to see if there is a record like:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

If there is `127.0.0.1`, it is the one causing the loop.

To get rid of it, you should not edit that file, but check other places to make it properly generated.

Check all files under `/etc/systemd/network` and if you find a record like

```
DNS=127.0.0.1
```

delete that record. Also check `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and do the same if needed. Make sure you have at least one or two DNS servers configured, such as

```
DNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

After doing all that, restart the systemd services to put your changes into effect:
systemctl restart systemd-networkd systemd-resolved

After that, verify that `DNS=127.0.0.1` is no more in the `resolv.conf` file:

```
cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Finally, trigger re-creation of the DNS pods

```
kubectl -n kube-system delete pod -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```

**Summary:** The solution involves getting rid of what looks like a DNS lookup loop from the host DNS configuration. Steps vary between different resolv.conf managers/implementations.

Comment: "hacky solution" did the trick, yet "proper solution" (preferred over "hacky") - `systemd-resolved.service` is inactive (dead) and it is also disabled

Comment: @alexus Glad that it worked out. The preferred solution assumes that your system uses systemd + it's DNS resolver service. If that's not the case, you can investigate and find out where the nameservers are read from, and how they are populated/added, as I mentioned in the summary. 

The reason for the 1st solution to be hacky is the following: Loop detection of CoreDNS is necessary, and therefore the crash is the expected behavior. So, ideally, the loop needs to be removed/fixed.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir I am using `ubuntu 16.04` and I dont have `resolv.conf` of `systemd`. Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are `nameserver 127.0.1.1
search APSDC.local`. I am getting the same coredns crashloopbackoff. Is it because of the `127.0.1.1` IP. Can you please suggest any good solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466359/coredns-crashloopbackoff-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 5):

For minikube on Ubuntu using the "none" driver,
you can use the following flag to get it work with no other changes required -
`sudo minikube start --extra-config=kubelet.resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3511) relates issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's some shell hackery that automates [Utku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005102/utku-%c3%96zdemir)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414041/3798657):

```
# remove loop from DNS config files
sudo find /etc/systemd/network /etc/systemd/resolved.conf -type f \
    -exec sed -i '/^DNS=127.0.0.1/d' {} +

# if necessary, configure some DNS servers (use cloudfare public)
if ! grep '^DNS=.*' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf; then
    sudo sed -i '$aDNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
fi

# restart systemd services
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd systemd-resolved

# force (re-) creation of the dns pods
kubectl -n kube-system delete pod -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```

Comment: I am still getting crashloopbackoff after executing ./shellhackery.sh on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

In `ubuntu 16.04` maybe you can have issues with `dnsmasq`. It sets automatically a loopback address. I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466359/coredns-crashloopbackoff-in-kubernetes/60139992#60139992) a similar response.