# Kubernetes CoreDNS in CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos7, coredns

I understand that this question is asked dozen times, but nothing has helped me through internet searching.

My set up:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Docker Version: 18.06.1-ce
Kubernetes: v1.12.3
```

Installed by official guide and this one:https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-centos-7/

CoreDNS pods are in Error/CrashLoopBackOff state.

```
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-8phwt                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          31m
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-rn2qc                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          31m
```

My /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Also tried with my local dns-resolver(router)

```
nameserver 10.10.10.1
```

Setup and init:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.10.10.3 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.1.0/16
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

I tried to solve this with: 
Editing the coredns: root@kub~]# kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
and changing

```
proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
```

directly to

```
proxy . 10.10.10.1
```

or 
    proxy . 8.8.8.8

Also tried to:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deployment coredns -o yaml |   sed 's/allowPrivilegeEscalation: false/allowPrivilegeEscalation: true/g' |   kubectl apply -f -
```

And still nothing helps me.

Error from the logs:

```
plugin/loop: Seen "HINFO IN 7847735572277573283.2952120668710018229." more than twice, loop detected
```

The other thread - [coredns pods have CrashLoopBackOff or Error state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075796/coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state) didnt help at all, becouse i havent hit any solutions that were described there. Nothing helped.

Comment: Can you post the logs? You can get them through `kubectl logs coredns-576cbf47c7-8phwt` for example

Comment: Updated, yep, sorry,  forgot to add the actual error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [coredns pods have CrashLoopBackOff or Error state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075796/coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state)

Comment: I didnt hit any of the presented solutions except a "hacky" - removing the loop plugin.

Answer (score 14):

**Even I have got such error and I successfully managed to work by below steps.**

**However, you missed 8.8.4.4**

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

run following commands to restart daemon and docker service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker
```

If you are using kubeadm make sure you delete an entire cluster from master and provision cluster again.

```
kubectl drain <node_name> --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
kubectl delete node <node_name>
kubeadm reset
```

Once You Provision the new cluster

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

It Should give below expected Result

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-node-gldlr          2/2     Running   0          24s
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-lpnj6   1/1     Running   0          40s
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-xnb5r   1/1     Running   0          40s
kube-system   kube-proxy-kkb7b           1/1     Running   0          40s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-osboxes     1/1     Running   0          10s
```

Comment: I resolve just with:

```nameserver 8.8.8.8```
```nameserver 8.8.4.4```

```sudo systemctl daemon-reload```

```sudo systemctl restart docker```

Comment: Hey @Altieres de Matos Even I have mentioned same commands man!!

Comment: @NarendranathReddy GREAT! Worked for me.

Comment: @SahilGulati Enjoy buddy, Happy Kubernetes!!

Comment: For me just `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart docker` worked. Even though coreDNS stays in loopback, one of the service IPs that wasn't reachable started responding again.

Comment: Why do you have to restart the entire cluster just to get the coredns pods back up running ?

Comment: I just found a working solution here , https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2087#issuecomment-432387727
tried and tested.

Answer (score 4):

$kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
delete ‘loop’ ,save and exit
restart master node. It was work for me.

Comment: This means coredns can't detect loops -- I did this and it worked (coredns could run and hostnames could resolve), but coredns had very high CPU utilization

Comment: @Hk Can you please put your answer in understandable format?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the the same issue in my local k8s in Docker (KIND) setup. CoreDns pod gets crashloop backoff error.

Steps followed to make the pod into running state:

As Tim Chan said in this post and by referring the github issues link, I did the following

1. `kubectl -n kube-system edit configmaps coredns -o yaml`
2. modify the section
   `forward . /etc/resolv.conf` with `forward . 172.16.232.1` (mycase i set 8.8.8.8 for the timebeing)
3. Delete one of the Coredns Pods, or can wait for sometime - the pods will be in running state.

Answer (score 1):

Usually happens when coredns can't talk to the kube-apiserver:

Check that your `kubernetes` service is in the default namespace:

```
$ kubectl get svc kubernetes
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        130d
```

Then (you might have to create a pod):

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system exec -it <any-pod-with-shell> sh
# ping kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
PING kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.0.1): 56 data bytes
```

Also, try hitting port `443` from the port:

```
# telnet kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 443 # or
# curl kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error is:

> connect: no route to host","time":"2021-03-19T14:42:05Z"}
> crashloopbackoff

in the log showed by `kubectl -n kube-system logs coredns-d9fdb9c9f-864rz`

The issue is mentioned in https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/loop#troubleshooting-loops-in-kubernetes-clusters

tldr;
Reason: `/etc/resolv.conf` got updated somehow. The original one is at `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:
e.g:

> nameserver 172.16.232.1

Quick fix, edit Corefile:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system edit configmaps coredns -o yaml
```

to replace `forward . /etc/resolv.conf` with `forward . 172.16.232.1`
e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . 172.16.232.1 {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-18T15:58:07Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "49996"
  uid: 428a03ff-82d0-4812-a3fa-e913c2911ebd
```

Done, after that, may need to restart the docker

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Update: it could be fixed by just `sudo systemctl restart docker`