# How to get IP address of azure IoT hub instead of hostname

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub

I have azure Iot hub with connection details like address, remote_username, remote_password which my device uses to connect to the IoT hub. I am running mosquitto which uses below configuration settings in order to connect to azure Iot hub:

```
connection iot-bridge
log_type all
address apsdc.azure-devices.net:8883
remote_username apsdc.azure-devices.net/Device1
remote_password SharedAccessSignature sr=apsdc.azure-devices.net&sig=ofIUhB3Tx6r3lGruCveI166ua655y8wA7U5dffqxBqY%3D&se=1534941834&skn=iothubowner
remote_clientid Device1

....
other settings...
....
```

Mosquitto on device connects to the iot-bridge which is `apsdc.azure-devices.net` using the provided username and sas password. I was wondering if its possible to use any public IP address instead of `apsdc.azure-devices.net`. Is there any settings on azure to get the IP address. Thanks

Comment: You might want to add your comments to this user voice request: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/15714243-iot-hub-network-address

Comment: @DominicBetts From the link you mentioned, it looks like using IP address is not a good idea.?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the IP address of a hub can change without notice - from the link, I'm not sure exactly what circumstances might trigger a change.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2017/02/version-1-4-11-released/), you can recompile Mosquitto to support DNS so that you no longer have to connect to an IP address.

Comment: I am using kuberneter v1.13 and its coredns always remains in `CrashLoopBackOff` due to which DNS is not working and thus mosquitto is also not able to connect to IoT hub and this is why I wanted to get the IP address. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466359/coredns-crashloopbackoff-in-kubernetes